# Regex for domain name only

Tags: javascript, regex, url, dns

I'm asking my users to write their domain name.

**I'm looking for inputs of these types (=good):**

```
http://www.Domain.com
http://Domain.com
https://www.Domain.com
https://Domain.com
www.Domain.com
Domain.com
http://no.matter.how.many.Domain.com
https://no.matter.how.many.Domain.com
no.matter.how.many.Domain.com
http://www.Domain.com/
https://www.Domain.com/
http://no.matter.how.many.Domain.com/
https://no.matter.how.many.Domain.com/
www.Domain.com/
Domain.com/
```

I'm want to reject any input that not in this format. 
**Bad inputs, for example:**

```
http://www.Domain.com/page
http://www.Domain.com/page.html
http://www.Domain.com/page/page2
and so on...
```

Can you help me with a suitable RegEx?

Thank you!

Comment: which tool/language are you using! and what have tried..

Comment: use this [link](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) its helpful for you

Comment: javascript regular-expression. Most of regex-pattern i have checked was for full url (inludes pages and more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
(https?://)?(www.)?([A-Za-z]+\.){1,}([A-Za-z]{2,})/?
```

Comment: this would still match the bad inputs..you should have `$` at the end

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex

```
^(https?://)?[^/]+/?$
```

`^`depicts the start of string

`$` depicts the end of string

`?` matches preceding group or char optionally..